# Best way to clean a temporary files if script can be interrupted

Tags: python

a command line script needs to clean up temporary files it has created for its use before existing. Assume that the script can be interrupted during execution as well.
which of following should you do in script?

a:) use atexit module

b:)  use os.tempnam() to create temp file

c:) define a_del_function

d:) None Of above

Comment: You can use `try-finally`(or define your own context protocol  and use the `with` statement). But this may not handle interrupts like `os._exit`.

Comment: Have a look at [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `try`/`finally` to do [clean-up](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions). If you need to handle OS level interrupts use [signals](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html).

**`Try`/`finally` example**

```
try:
    create_temp_file()
finally:
    delete_temp_file()
```

**Signal example**

```
from signal import *
import sys

def clean(*args):
    delete_temp_file()
    sys.exit(0)

for sig in (SIGABRT, SIGBREAK, SIGILL, SIGINT, SIGSEGV, SIGTERM):
    signal(sig, clean)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap everything in a `try`/`finally` clause. The cleanup part goes under `finally`:

```
try:
    # do everything
finally:
    # cleanup logic
```

When you interrupt the program, a `SystemExit` exception is raised, and the `finally` clause is executed.
It allows to do more general things than just deleting temporary files.

Comment: But it does not clean up when your program crashes or gets killed the hard way. Other methods do.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own context manager here:

```
import os
class create_temp_file(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        """Define entry point actions here"""

        self.filename = os.tempnam()
        self.file_obj = open(self.filename, 'w')
        return self.file_obj

    def __exit__(self, ex_type, ex_value, ex_traceback):
        """define cleanup actions here"""

        self.file_obj.close()
        os.remove(self.filename)
```

Now use `with` statement, it is pythonic way of doing try-finally

```
with create_temp_file() as f:
    #do something with file here
```

But `os.tempnam` is not safe, better use the [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile) module to do such things.

> RuntimeWarning: tempnam is a potential security risk to your program

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=True) as f:
   #do something with f here
```

If `delete` is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed.(or when file object is garbage collected)

Answer (score 0):

I would say d) none of the above.

Either you use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` with the `delete` option True, or you use some platform specific magic to have the OS do your cleanup (which is wrapped up already in `os.tempfile()`)

On Windows you can use the 'D' flag to open to make a file which gets removed when the last handle is closed:

```
with open(filename, "wD") as fd:
     ...
```

on Linux and other POSIX systems you can simply `os.unlink` the file while you have it still open, with the same effect that it gets cleaned up for you.

```
with open(filename, "w") as fd:
     os.unlink(filename)
     ...
```

But as we are all lazy in the end `os.tmpfile()` does all this already.